# Is there an easier way to make something display only in the non-error state? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some text/images that I only want to display in the normal state of a form -- that is, it hasn't been submitted, yet. If the user submitted the form, and it is returned to the browser with errors, I'd like to display something else. Currently, I'm using:

```
<% if !@user.errors.empty? -%>
    # Leaving this area blank.
<% else -%>
    # Inserting something here
<% end -%>
```

But this seems a bit heavy and there has to be a simpler way.

This is probable really simple to do, but I can't find anything about it -- though, I'm probably not phrasing the question right.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you post some pseudo-code of what you have in mind for something simpler? If all you want is clarity, you might try moving off some code to partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine something completely different right now. But why don't you use only the `if` statement when you only need one branch of it?

```
<% if @users.errors.empty? %>
  # Inserting something here
<% end %>
```